# Shared instance of Coredata managedobjectContext and private ivars

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Up until now i was using a shared Coredata instance. Where in the view controllers i'd call `[[Storage instance] managedObjectContext]` to pass around in the view controllers!

I could be brutally wrong you say? please tell me why.

I noticed in most examples, viewControllers have managedObjectContexts in @private in header files. Why do we need private calls here?

Lastly we declare like

```
  NSManagedObjectContext *_managedObjectContext;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

then in viewController.m

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

whats the significance of "**_**"managedObjectContext. why the underscore ?

Lastly, how would all this affect iCloud? In one tutorial the writer said,

> ivars should be private, and it is really important that all code
>   always goes through the accessor methods to ensure that these are
>   properly initialized. Without the funny *_* then KVC might "help" us
>   too much. With iCloud importing  data asynchronously, there are more
>   timing and multi-threading issues

Without the funny *_* ... please explain wats going on here..

```
@interface LStorage : NSObject {

@private
    NSString *identifier;   
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;   
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

+ (LStorage *) instance;

in  LStorage.m

+ (LStorage *) instance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (instance == nil) {
            instance = [[LStorage alloc] initWithIdentifier:kIdentifier];
        }
    }   
    return instance;
}
//identifier is just used to name the mom model filename.
- (id) initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)anIdentifier {
    self = [super init];

    if(self != nil) {
        identifier = anIdentifier;
    }

    return self;
}
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil) {
        // Make life easier by adopting the new NSManagedObjectContext concurrency API
        // the NSMainQueueConcurrencyType is good for interacting with views and controllers since
        // they are all bound to the main thread anyway

        if(IOS_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0")){
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

        [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
            // even the post initialization needs to be done within the Block
            [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
        }];
        managedObjectContext = moc;
        }else{
            managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        }
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing how your NSManagedObjectContext is initialised, but I am assuming you are using the boiler plate code provided by Apple. If that's the case, you should have an assessor like:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
        return _managedObjectContext;
    // Code to initialise and return context here
}
```

Note that the `managedObjectContext` is lazily loaded in this method. This means the context is only created the first time the method is accessed via `self.managedObjectContext` or `[self managedObjectContext]` (or externally if you property is accessible from other classes).

Now imagine that this method was never accessed, so your `_managedObjectContext` ivar is pointing to nil or memory garbage. If you try to access the ivar directly, you will get a crash because there is no `NSManagedObjectContext` stored in that block of memory.

This is also the reason it is common practice to add an underscore (_) at the beginning or end of an ivar name, so to avoid you accidentally accessing the ivar directly rather than via its synthesized getter.

If the ivar is simply named `managedObjectContext` it is easier to make that mistake i.e. instead of writing `self.managedObjectContext` you might just write `managedObjectContext` and all of sudden you are accessing the ivar directly.

So basically what the `synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;` means is ***synthesize a getter (and possibly setter) method called `managedObjectContext` and assign it to an ivar called _managedObjectContext.***

Comment: your initialiser is fine, I'm more interested in your `managedObjectContext` method inside that class.

Comment: just added.. but i didnt conform to _managed underscoring! i should do that now that i understand this!